# Spring Security upgrade, SecurityContextPersistanceFilter to SecurityContextHolderFilter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, javabeans, deprecated

Im upgrading my project code to Spring 5, and Java 8 to 11. At first for the authentication.xml we used HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter. Now we are trying to replace it with SecurityContextHolderFilter but not able to. As a temporary fix we used the deprecated class SecurityContextPersistanceFilter and it works for now but still need the solution for this.

The bean config in Java 8 used to be this

Authorization.xml -> Java 8/Spring 2

```
<bean id="httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter"/>
```

The temporary fix --> Java 11 (Its working but the class is deprecated)

```
<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter"/>
```

The actual Required Fix --> Spring 5

```
<bean id ="securityContextHolderFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter">
   <constructor-arg name="securityContextRepository" ref="securityContextRepository"/>
</bean>
<bean name="securityContextRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository"/>

<sec:http security-context-repository-ref="securityContextRepository" security-context-explicit-save="true">
<sec: form-login/>
</sec:http>
```

I tried the last bean configuration in my FilterChain, but the principal header of my preAuth userDetail class comes as null.

Please let me know of a solution which fits my problem, anything helps.
Thanks